# Asp.Net Web API Client check Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

I am creating a client application to retrieve data from a web api , some data needs the `Authorization` header in the GET request in order to be retrieved i am achieving this by adding a new `AuthenticationHeaderValue` instance to the `HttpClient` `DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization` which contains the username and password the user enters and the scheme value which is "Basic" for this API ,i want a consistent method to check if the user have entered the correct credentials or not

Answer (score 0):

Check the tutorial is this page: http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.mx/2016/10/implementing-basic-authentication-in.html

It's very basic and should not be used in production, you should use this instead: http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.mx/2016/11/aspnet-web-api-token-authentication.html

Dunno if it helps you , hope it does

Comment: thank you , but i am working on the client side and don't have access to the server , so i need a method to check if my request to add the authorized header was accepted or not i.e. if the user has entered the correct username and password